# add months in an existing data frame python

Tags: python, pandas

| Year | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 2017 | 200 |
| 2018 | 250 |
| 2019 | 300 |

Given the table above, is there a way to add months to each year ? For eg: 2017 should have months jan to dec and the same price carried forward in all of the 12 months for all the years listed in a data frame in Pandas?

| Year | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 2017/01/01 | 200 |
| 2017/02/01 | 200 |
| 2017/03/01 | 200 |
| 2017/04/01 | 200 |
| 2017/05/01 | 200 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better answer out there (I know very little Pandas), but one thing that comes to mind is:

Get the `date` represented by your numeric `"Year"`. That will give you January 1st at midnight in that *Year*. You can drop the time part (the *"hour"*, if you may) and keep just the date (January 1st of that year)

At this point you'll have your first row being *January* (month 1). Then you can replicate the row changing the `"Year"`'s month to 2 (February), 3 (March)... until... 12 (December) and insert it back in the Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"Year": 2017, "Price": 200},
    {"Year": 2018, "Price": 300},
    {"Year": 2019, "Price": 400},
])
df["Year"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Year"], format='%Y').dt.date

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for i in range(2, 13):
        row["Year"] = row["Year"].replace(month=i)
        df = pd.concat([df, row.to_frame().T])
df = df.sort_values(['Year']).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

#           Year Price
# 0   2017-01-01   200
# 1   2017-02-01   200
# 2   2017-03-01   200
# 3   2017-04-01   200
# 4   2017-05-01   200
# 5   2017-06-01   200
# 6   2017-07-01   200
# 7   2017-08-01   200
# 8   2017-09-01   200
# 9   2017-10-01   200
# 10  2017-11-01   200
# 11  2017-12-01   200
# 12  2018-01-01   300
# 13  2018-02-01   300
# 14  2018-03-01   300
# 15  2018-04-01   300
# 16  2018-05-01   300
# 17  2018-06-01   300
# 18  2018-07-01   300
# 19  2018-08-01   300
# 20  2018-09-01   300
# 21  2018-10-01   300
# 22  2018-11-01   300
# 23  2018-12-01   300
# 24  2019-01-01   400
# 25  2019-02-01   400
# 26  2019-03-01   400
# 27  2019-04-01   400
# 28  2019-05-01   400
# 29  2019-06-01   400
# 30  2019-07-01   400
# 31  2019-08-01   400
# 32  2019-09-01   400
# 33  2019-10-01   400
# 34  2019-11-01   400
# 35  2019-12-01   400
```

Comment: This is not an efficient solution because you are modifying the dataframe you are iterating over, which requires a new memory allocation at every step. If you like the iteration method, it would be more efficient to iterate over a range, append a new record (yyyy-mm-dd, price) to a list, and create the revised dataframe from that list at the very end. However, it does work and is simple to understand, so I appreciate it on those merits.

Comment: Yeah, the time complexity is high. It takes over 20 mins to resolve 27,000 rows.

Comment: @FalloutATS21, if you think there's a better answer out there (which... there seems to be) you should probably mark that one as _"accepted"_  rather than mine?. Just in case another reader finds this thread. As I mentioned in the original "disclaimer", I am not very knowledgeable on Pandas 

Comment: Not at all! I like the answer as it was able to teach me something new! Thank you! @BorrajaX

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
df.columns = [i.strip() for i in df.columns]
df['Year'] = df['Year'].apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=str(x), end=str(x+1), freq='1M').strftime('%m'))
df = df.explode('Year').reset_index(drop=True)

>>>df
    Year    Price
0   01  200
1   02  200
2   03  200
3   04  200
4   05  200
5   06  200
6   07  200
7   08  200
8   09  200
9   10  200
10  11  200
11  12  200
12  01  250
13  02  250
14  03  250
15  04  250
16  05  250
17  06  250
18  07  250
19  08  250
20  09  250
21  10  250
22  11  250
23  12  250
24  01  300
25  02  300
26  03  300
27  04  300
28  05  300
29  06  300
30  07  300
31  08  300
32  09  300
33  10  300
34  11  300
35  12  300
```

Comment: This is probably the most fun solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataframe with months 1-12

Cross merge that with your original data

Create a date out of the year, month, and day 1

Sample code:

```
years = [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022]
prices = [200, 250, 300, 350, 350, 317]
your_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[(x, y) for x, y in zip(years, prices)], columns=["Year","Price"])

months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
m_df = pd.DataFrame(data=months, columns=["Month"])

final_df = full_df.merge(your_df, how="cross")

final_df["Year"] = [datetime(y, m, 1) for y,m in zip(full_df.Year, full_df.Month)]
final_df = final_df.drop(columns="Month")
final_df
```

[image: Final output]